# Filter dataframe by condition or

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter the df3 by condition "or". But obviously something messed up with the syntax:

```
    condition_101 = df3['ID1_G'].isin(df5['ID2_G'].unique())
    condition_102 = df3['ID1_G'].isin(df5['ID2_G'].unique())
    condition_103 = df3['ID2_G'].isin(df5['ID2_G'].unique())
    condition_104 = df3['ID2_G'].isin(df5['ID1_G'].unique())

    df4 = df3.loc[condition_101 or condition_102 or condition_103 or condition_104, ALL]
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: don't use `'or'`, use the sign `|`

Comment: so easy... Thank!